# Android V2 embedding

Tags: android, flutter, dart, migration, tflite

> the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

I used the latest version of flutter and 2.10 version
and i got the same problemme
i'm using Vscode i want to know how to configure kotlin file

a explication or tuto

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.